# Weblogic 10.3 weblogic.jar classpath issues

Tags: weblogic, classpath

I am upgrading an old WLS8.1 app to 10.3 (11g)
My ant build includes only the new weblogic.jar in the compile classpath and the build runs with no issues but when I include weblogic.jar as a libeary in the IDE (Intellij) i see many unresolved imports (for example: weblogic.xml.xpath.DOMXPath) when I check the weblogic.jar I see that the classes are indeed missing from it.

compiling with verbose revealed that by including weblogic.jar in the ant classpath, many other jars in the BEA_HOME/modules are loaded to the classpath as well (for example: com.bea.core.xml.weblogic.xpath_1.4.0.0.jar)

Can anyone explain what is going on?

How can I fix my IDE classpath - do I need to import all the module-jars?

Many of the module jars seems like they are there to support old deprecated weblogic 8 APIs (like: weblogic.xml.xpath.DOMXPath) how can I exclude these modules from my ant build? (I want to expose the APIs I need to upgrade)

Thanks,

NY

Answer (score 0):

The default class loader is replaced by the WebLogic one which adds the WebLogic specific classes and some lib folders to your CLASSPATH. You should have some support for J2EE in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but this might be resolved by using wlfullclient.jar instead of weblogic.jar.